# Call static javascript file's function from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just starting to work with Node JS so it might be that I'm confused about what's the best approach but here is my situation:

I want to load some information through REST API calls then work with it and serve it to a webpage.

I currently can do this with a regular JS script. However, it takes around 30 seconds to load and process this information so I was thinking to do something like this:

- Use Node Js to load the information from API every 5/10 minutes
- Have Node JS serve the HTML/CSS files and also a static script file that will present the information (fill a table, reorder some divs...)
- Have Node JS call a function from the static script and pass as
  parameter the information it recovered from the API so the
  information is presented

The idea is that this way, the information will always be ready in Node and take less to load

I know how to do the first point, should be able to figure the second one but I have no idea on how to proceed with the third one. I would also be fine with going the other way around and have the static script call Node every few minutes but I'm also not sure on how to go about that.

Is there a way to call a static script's function from Node?
Or should I try a different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: With `static script` you mean clientside code right?

Comment: Create a cache system for your REST API. So you don't have to wait for every request and don't have to create html files.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you have a javascript file that needs to be served to the user together with the HTML and CSS files through Node? Or do you have a web server seperate from Node that hosts those files? Or do you mean you need to call a function inside the node script? In other words, I don't get which file is supposed to be server side and which file is client side. Or are you using the same javascript files both server side in node, as client side in the app?

Comment: http already had cache system

Comment: @ Jonas Yes, I mean client side, sorry

Comment: I'll try to explain better:
I have client side javascript file that presents information,
I am making API calls from node,
I want to pass the result of the API call to the client side script

Comment: From node.js, you can't call a script in the client (you have no connection to the client).  You can either have the client regularly ask the server for updates via an Ajax call (this is called polling) or you can have the client connect to the server with a persistent webSocket or socket.io connection and then the server can directly send an update to the client any time one is available and the client would have its own code to process the update and display it.

Comment: Ideally, it would be easier to fix the problem on the api side...